# Teradata Show people who have over 10 occurrences on the list

Tags: sql, reporting-services, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I need some help figuring this one out. See the Teradata query below. I am only trying to show the people (l_name, f_name) who have 10 or more occurrences of calls under 60 seconds. For example if a person has 9 occurrences of calls under 60 seconds, none of those records would appear in the results. However if they have 11 occurrences, all 11 records would appear in the results.

```
select 
    group_name, device_id as record, starttime, length, csr_id, 
    f_name, l_name, sum(score), sum(poss_score), Manager, 
    case 
       when gro.name in ('Group A’) then 'Group 1’
       when gro.name in ('Group B’) then 'Group 2’
       when gro.name in ('Group c’) then 'Group 3’
       else gro.name 
    end as Group_Name
from 
    rep_voice re
left join 
    qa_complete com on re.record_ck = com.record_ck
join 
    users_groups us on us.user_ck = re.user_ck and us.current = 1
where 
    cast(re.starttime as date) between TRUNC((CURRENT_DATE-7)) and LAST_DAY((CURRENT_DATE-1)) 
    and duration<= 60
    and name in ('ABCD','EFGH','IJKL','LMNO')
qualify rank () over (partition by us.user_ck order by cast (us.modifiedon as date) desc) =1 
group by 
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,us.user_ck,us.modifiedon
```

Comment: I understand your question.  But I have no idea what the query has to do with it.  Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully-familiar with your schema layout - just as Gordon mentioned - but I think what you are looking for is this:

```
select * from call_table
qualify count(*) over (partition by user_caller)>=10
```